# Extract values from Array{Any} in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia, any

I have a text file containing special characters, text and some numbers and I need to extract from it some values which appear every n-th row. Since the file has around 20k rows, I want the algorithm to find first and next rows. I've read text file to matrix with readdlm(), but the type of array is ANY, and findfirst() gives and error "access to undefined reference". Could you give me some guidance, please?

Regards

Mike

@Jubobs Here is results file :

https://copy.com/i9GeXhK0qHdfwpkT

I need to extract values for node 79 , which starts at row 10
So i want the algorithm to find the row file[10,1] and get the value file[10,2], and then next and so on.

```
file=readdlm("results.txt")  
findfirst(file,"79")  

access to undefined reference  
while loading In[13], in expression starting on line 1  

 in findnext at array.jl:1034 (repeats 2 times)
```

Comment: Don't have time to solve this now, but I think the problem is that (1) `file[10,1]` is actually `Float64`, so looking for the `String` `79` won't give you results, and (2) looking for `79.0` won't help either, because `findnext` uses `==` to compare, so you don't want to be comparing Floats.

Comment: as @NilsGudat suggested above, try to explicitly specify the `type` argument of the `readdlm()` function to be `ASCIIString`. refer to [this](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/io-network/?highlight=readdlm#Base.readdlm)

Comment: This has been answered (more or less) in the [julia user group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/julia-users/q3Buwe385IM/UBQN-keNxGkJ)

Answer (score 1):

Best bet would be to read the file as a string and search through it using a regex (or manually if you prefer). It doesn't make much sense to open your txt file as a delimited one (probably that's where your error stems from). Instead, do the following:

```
f = open("results.txt") # f <: some kind of IO object
data = readall(f) # data <: AbstractString
close(f)
```

I hope this helps.